# Why would a bash script create a file with the name of one of my variables?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I'm using this bash script to maintain 3 backups of my server. For some reason, it randomly creates an empty file with the name of one of my variables. The variable name it chooses is seemingly random, and it doesn't create the file every single time that it's run.

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS

The script works perfectly as intended. I'm just wondering why bash creates the file sometimes.

NOTE: I have omitted some sensitive information such as the Samba address, and location of the CIFS credentials. This was intentional and is correct in my actual script.

I'm running this script from a cron job with the command `bash backup.bash`, so bash is explicitly used to run the script

```
#!/bin/bash

## The number of backups that we want to keep
MAX_BACKUPS=3

## The directory to store the backups
BACKUP_DIR="OMITTED"

## The address of the Samba Share
REMOTE_ADDR="OMITTED"

## What we want to name the backup
BACKUP_NAME="$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")_backup.tar.gz"

## Mount the Samba Share to the backup directory
mount -t cifs -o credentials=OMITTED,noperm $REMOTE_ADDR $BACKUP_DIR

## Make todays backup
tar -cpzvf $BACKUP_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME --exclude-from=/backup_scripts/backup.exclude /

## The number of backups that we now have
COUNT="$(find $BACKUP_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*_backup.tar.gz' | wc -l )"

## If we have more backups than MAX_BACKUPS
if ((COUNT > MAX_BACKUPS)); then
  ## Delete the oldest file (DETERMINED BY MODIFICATION DATE)
  cd $BACKUP_DIR
  rm "$(ls -t | tail -1)"
fi

# Unmount the Samba Share for safety
umount $BACKUP_DIR
```

Comment: It probably won't fix anything, but you should quote your variables

Comment: How exactly does the name of the "empty file with the name of one of my variables" look? Which of your script variables would contain this name? Please provide some examples. Additionally, what on the first view strikes me as odd is the nested quoting when creating `BACKUP_NAME`, a thing I would try to avoid in my scripts. Another best practice is to enclose shell variables into curly brackets to avoid ambiguities: `${BACKUP_NAME}`.

Comment: what happens when the script is logged with `-x` to show what is going on?

Comment: In what directory do the files appear? It may also help to specifically list which variables are appearing -- is it every variable you use in the script?

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @Murphy, quotes inside a command substitution are just fine, though of course not necessary here (as aren't the quotes around them, since that's an assignment). But they would be necessary in something like `somecmd "$(date +"%F %T")"`

Comment: But I'm not sure if this question can be answered if it's not possible to get a verifiable sample of a script that causes the issue. Without that we might as well conclude that "it's cosmic radiation", or that your computer is broken.

Comment: I can imagine `((COUNT > MAX_BACKUPS))` creating a file called `MAX_BACKUPS` if accidentally executed with a non-bash shell

Comment: @steeldriver as a matter of fact, the last file created WAS called MAX_BACKUPS. This script is run with a cron job. the command I'm using is `bash backup.bash`. So I'm explicitly using bash to execute the script. The folder that the file gets created in is the same folder as the script itself.

Comment: @Murphy I wasn't aware of that. Thank you.

Comment: @ilkkachu thumbs up for 'cosmic radiation' explanation! :)

Comment: Since a lot of people (including me) will blaim the `>` symbol inside arithmetic evaluation `((....))` you could replace `if ((COUNT > MAX_BACKUPS))` with `if [[ "${COUNT}" -gt "${MAX_BACKUPS}" ]]` and tell us if the problem remains.... More over Ubuntu 16 uses i think bash 4.3 and i think there are some bugs related to parameters expansion within arithmetic evaluation

Comment: actually, I just changed `if ((COUNT > MAX_BACKUPS))` to `if ((${COUNT} > ${MAX_BACKUPS}))` and the problem is gone!

Answer (score 2):

Edit: as @StéphaneChazelas pointed out, the problem is likely that your script isn't being invoked with `bash`, and the `(( ))` construct won't work.  Try running it from a `bash` shell or with `bash my_script.sh`

Also, that `rm` has the potential to fail spectacularly.  Please read [this FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099).

Comment: The problem is not with not expanding `$COUNT`. `((COUNT > MAX_BACKUPS))` is correct in ksh/bash/zsh. Most likely, the script is not being interpreted by any of those shells here, maybe because it's run as `sh the-script` or `. the-script` from within a `sh` script. And then `((COUNT > MAX_BACKUPS))` is interpreted as a nested subshell, like in `( (COUNT > MAX_BACKUPS ) )` instead of an arithmetic expression.

Comment: Thanks.  So, does POSIX only have `$(( ))`?  If so, would you have to use `[ ]` and `-gt` style operators for comparison?

Comment: Yes, or `[ "$((COUNT > MAX_BACKUPS))" -ne 0 ]` for instance. Though `[ "$COUNT" -gt "$MAX" ]` would be more canonical (and would also be portable to the Bourne shell would you ever come across very old systems)

Comment: I'm running it via a CRON job and the command I'm using explicitly calls bash. `bash backup.bash`